# PyQt/PySide tableWidget.setItem behaving wierdly

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget

I've this piece of code that is behaving wierdly.

```
data = {
    "test1":100,
    "test2":200,
    "test3":300 }

self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(list(data.viewitems())[0]))
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))

for i, name in enumerate(data):
    item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, item1)
    item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(data[name])
    self.tableWidget.setItem(1,i,item2)
```

It shoudl create a table like the 'data', but it's skipping the 'test2' item,

But if I somehow create them manualy like this they work.

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("test1")
self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("test2")
self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("test3")
self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
```

Comment: This `self.tableWidget.setItem(1,i,item2)` should be `self.tableWidget.setItem(i,1,item2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @xndrme said in comment:

> This self.tableWidget.setItem(1,i,item2) should be
>   self.tableWidget.setItem(i,1,item2)

I've make test with PyQt4 and Python26 and second column is empty for me, unless I convert `data[name]` to string like this:

```
item2 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data[name]))
```

also this line `self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(list(data.viewitems())[0]))` gives this error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'viewitems'` so I've simply set 2 columns `self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)`